# How to prevent browser resize affect printing format css?

Tags: html, css

When i print a html page in full screen the printing format just look nice, but when the window minimized or resized not in full screen, the font will getting bigger in printing format.

```
  @media print{}...
  @page{}...
```

I tried this method but no luck.  How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Try using px, instead of percentage when making a print page.

Comment: @jae.phoenix but when printing the font if using px will became smaller?

Comment: sorry I should have clarified.  Your fonts will be fine,  you have to give the <div> and <table> that you use a fixed width.  Then the browser wont be able to push the content smaller.